# How can I use a 2D array as input? expected flatten_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 1, 2, 5)

Tags: python, tensorflow

I saw many similar questions, but I didn't get the answer to myself from those topics.

I'm working on RL with the gym.

I had an input array with shape (5,) and the code was working, but when I changed the array shape to (2,5) with the same model structure, things started to go wrong. For some reason my data converts to a 4-dimensional array.

And it says :

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected flatten_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 1, 2, 5)
```

The full code looks like this:

```
from gym import Env
from gym.spaces import Discrete, Box
import numpy as np

class Game(Env):
    def __init__(self):
        self.action_space = Discrete(3)
        self.observation_space = Box(low=np.array([[0, 0, -180, 0, 0],[0,0,0,0,0]]), high=np.array([[500, 500, 180, 100, 0],[500,500,500,500,500]]))
        self.state = self.observation_space.sample()

    def reset(self):
        # Reset shower temperature
        self.state = self.observation_space.sample()
        # Reset shower time
        return self.state


env = Game()
states = env.observation_space.shape  #(2,5)
actions = env.action_space.n  #3

def build_model(states, actions):
    model = Sequential()
    
    model.add(Flatten(input_shape=states))  
    model.add(Dense(32, input_dim=26, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(actions, activation='sigmoid', input_shape=states))

    return model

model = build_model(states, actions)

def build_agent(model, actions): 
    policy = BoltzmannQPolicy()
    memory = SequentialMemory(limit=50000, window_length=1)
    dqn = DQNAgent(model=model, memory=memory, policy=policy, 
                  nb_actions=actions, nb_steps_warmup=30, target_model_update=1e-2)
    return dqn

model.summary()

dqn = build_agent(model, actions)
dqn.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=1e-3), metrics=['accuracy'] )
dqn.fit(env, nb_steps=100000, visualize=True, verbose=1)
```

**Edited:** I have follow error and seems like array converts to 4D when creating a Q-Values in:

**keras-rl/rl/agents/dqn.py| DQNAgent:**

```
def forward(self, observation):
        # Select an action.
        state = self.memory.get_recent_state(observation)
        q_values = self.compute_q_values(state) #<----
```

Then, in **keras-rl/rl/agents/dqn.py| AbstractDQNAgent**:

```
def process_state_batch(self, batch):
    batch = np.array(batch) #<---- Here is converts to 4D 
    if self.processor is None:
        return batch
    return self.processor.process_state_batch(batch)

def compute_batch_q_values(self, state_batch):
    batch = self.process_state_batch(state_batch) #<----
    q_values = self.model.predict_on_batch(batch)
    assert q_values.shape == (len(state_batch), self.nb_actions)
    return q_values

def compute_q_values(self, state):
    q_values = self.compute_batch_q_values([state]).flatten() #<----
    assert q_values.shape == (self.nb_actions,)
    return q_values
```

**How can I use a 2D array as input?**

If you find the right solution, could you please explain why it is so, or share some resources where to read about it. Documentation by Tensorlow does not help at all.

Thank you!

Comment: "I had an input array with shape (5,) and the code was working, but when I changed the array shape to (2,5) with the same model structure, things started to go wrong. For some reason my data converts to a 4-dimensional array." I want to make sure I understand: you had correct code to which you gave a 1D array and got 3D output. Then you changed things so that you give it a 2D array, and you're *surprised* that the result is now 4D?

Comment: You see where the error message says `ValueError: Error when checking input: expected flatten_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 1, 2, 5)`? *When it was working*, `flatten_input` was as expected, right? So it if was expected to have 3 dimensions, then it had 3 dimensions, or it wouldn't have worked. Now, when you have an `array` with shape (1, 1, 2, 5)`, how many dimensions do you figure that has? Do you see why that doesn't meet the expectation?

Comment: Yeah, I got it. 1D converts to 3D and 2D converts to 4D. So how can I use a 2D array?

Comment: Why don't you write your box with shape (10) from the start ?

Comment: @CatalinaChircu I simplified Box to (6,) and my model strats to train worse with that 6th parameter. I believe the better model structure for my (6,) data exists, but I don't understand what model layers do and how their different parameters influence the training process. I thought to use a second row for parameters with little other sphere of responsibility from my Environment, just to be more convenient. As I got later it is not so for a model.

Answer (score 0):

This is your error :

> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected flatten_input to have
> 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 1, 2, 5)

According to the [Tensorflow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Flatten), Flatten takes a 3D array in input, not what you say you provided (i.e. 2D array).

On the other hand, are you sure that states is not 4D ? The error states that you gave a 4D array. Just make a `print(states)`, in order to check.

Now, rather than Flatten which does not seems to be the right choice here, you should use this to replace your first line in the model architecture:

```
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Reshape((10,), input_shape=(2, 5)))
```

Comment: I got wrong, with the array shape of (5,) code works well, with the same model structure. 
And yes, I'm sure my new array's shape is (2,5).

Comment: OK, then as I wrote above, I suggest you use the Reshape layer. Glatten inputs only 3D arrays, not 2D. And I do not understant what you mean by 'code working with shape  (5,)", you do not need flatten for that.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion.
Error when checking input: expected reshape_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 1, 2, 5)

Comment: I have added some additional information, check it.